# Quick Sort vs Radix Sort

Tags: sorting, quicksort, mergesort, radix-sort

In an coding exam, I was once asked this question:

> Assuming that you are *only* sorting Integers in ascending order, which algorithm do you use when you want to prioritize speed the most, but you also want to save space?

The options were:

> - LSD Radix Sort
> - Merge Sort
> - Quick Sort

I think an argument can be made between *LSD Radix Sort* and *Quicksort*.

*Radix sort* would function in $O(k n)$ and *Quicksort* would function in $O(n \log n)$ and worst case, $O(n^2)$

I chose *Radix Sort* as the answer, but I'm curious as to what others had to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends... If the number of input numbers is $n$, assuming the word-ram model of computation, a word size of $\Theta(\log n)$ bits, and worst-case inputs:

- Radix sort would require $O(n \log n)$  time and $O(n)$ auxiliary space.
- Quicksort with fixed or random pivot selection would require $O(n^2)$ worst-case time and $O(\log n)$ auxiliary space.
- Mergesort requires $O(n \log n)$ time and $O(n)$ auxiliary space.

Radix sort and Merge sort are then equivalent in this setting.

Notice that using quicksort with random pivoit selection results in a time complexity of $O(n \log n)$ with high probability. Selecting the pivot deterministically in a way that partitions the elements into two sets whose cardinalities are at most a constant factor apart gives your an algorithm with worst-case time complexity of $O(n \log n)$ and $O(\log n)$ auxiliary space.

Comment: Quicksort does require $O(\log n)$ extra space, regardless of recursive/iterative implementation (you need to keep track of the ranges; if you do the longer one immediately and postpone the shorter one each time, you need at most $\log_2 n$ ranges to register, ironically the worst space usage is in the best case time-wise).